# Trainning CNN Metric Learning gradient is constantly 1

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision, pytorch, loss-function

I'm training a CNN with shirts and bodycon photos. I have these two classes and about 15k photos. I'am trying to do Metric Learning with a Contrastive Loss, but my CNN is not learning because gradients are constantly 1. I'am using the pretrained resnet18 with Identity as last layer and cosine similarity for distances (I've tried with Euclidean too).  Does anybody know why ?
I'am defining the contrastive loss using label matrix, which is, for every pair of images, 1 if they belong to same class or 0 if not. The error I'am getting is about 2.9 all time, so it is not learning anything.

My code:

````
class ContrastiveLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, margin=5.0):
        super(ContrastiveLoss, self).__init__()
        self.margin = margin

    def forward(self, distances, labels):
      m = 5
      loss = 0 
      total = 0
      #Paralelizar
      distances = torch.from_numpy(distances).detach()
      labels = torch.from_numpy(labels).detach()
      # torch
      D_2 = torch.multiply(distances,distances)
      A = torch.multiply(D_2,labels)
      D_2_m  = (5 - D_2).clip(min=0)
      B = torch.multiply(D_2_m,(1 - labels))

      loss = torch.sum(A+B)/2
      total = len(A) * (len(A) - 1) / 2
      
      return loss / total
      

criterion = ContrastiveLoss()

from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

def get_label_matrix(labels):
  labels = labels.cpu().detach().numpy()
  lab_mat = np.empty([len(labels),len(labels)])
  for i,lab in enumerate(labels):
    for j,lab_2 in enumerate(labels):
      if lab == lab_2:
        lab_mat[i][j] = 0
      else:
        lab_mat[i][j] = 1
  return lab_mat

def train(CNN, train_loader, optimizer,criterion, num_epochs, model_name='model.ckpt', device='cpu'):
    CNN.train() # Set the model in train mode
    total_step = len(train_loader)
    losses_list = []
    criterion = criterion
    # Iterate over epochs
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # Iterate the dataset
        loss_avg = 0
        nBatches = 0
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            # Get batch of samples and labels
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.type(torch.LongTensor).to(device)
            outputs = CNN(images)

            distance = 1-pairwise_distances(outputs.cpu().detach().numpy(), metric="cosine")

            #distance = distance_matrix(outputs.cpu().detach().numpy(),outputs.cpu().detach().numpy())
            # Forward pass
            loss = criterion(distance,get_label_matrix(labels)).requires_grad_()
 
            # Backward and optimize
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            print(loss.data)
            print(loss.grad)
            loss.backward()
            print(loss.grad)
            optimizer.step()

            loss_avg += loss.cpu().item()
            nBatches+=1
            
            if (i+1) % 50 == 0:
                print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}' 
                       .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, total_step, loss_avg / nBatches))
        print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}' 
                       .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, total_step, loss_avg / nBatches))
        losses_list.append(loss_avg / nBatches)
        torch.save(CNN.state_dict(), SPRINT_path+ '/' + model_name)
          
    return losses_list 

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    resnet18 = resnet18.cuda()
    criterion = criterion.cuda()
    print("GPU ready to fight")

learning_rate = 0.01 
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(resnet18.parameters(),lr = learning_rate, 
                            weight_decay=1e-5, momentum=0.9)
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = resnet18.to(device)

losses = train(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion, num_epochs=10, model_name='toy_model.ckpt', device=device)

```
````